# Windows alternative CLI with no filename character limit

Tags: java, windows, maven, cmd, long-filenames

Trying to run mvn clean install -Dfull on a project returns back with a filename or extension too long error. I've been told you can install alternative CLI's on Windows that do not have the limit.

Can anyone lead me to where I can install this or am I not correct in my understanding ?

Thank you.

Update: I'm using Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: What do you mean by a filename too long? and how could that be?

Comment: @khmarbaise https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#maxpath

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be running the just released Windows 10 v1607, you can enable paths up to (about) 32 KB long either globally via registry or policies, or per-application via manifests.

From the just updated reference for [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx):

> **Tip**    Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, MAX_PATH limitations have been removed from common Win32 file and directory functions. However, you must opt-in to the new behavior.
>
> A registry key allows you to enable or disable the new long path behavior. To enable long path behavior set the registry key at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem LongPathsEnabled (Type: REG_DWORD)`. The key's value will be cached by the system (per process) after the first call to an affected Win32 file or directory function (list follows). The registry key will not be reloaded during the lifetime of the process. In order for all apps on the system to recognize the value of the key, a reboot might be required because some processes may have started before the key was set.
>
> The registry key can also be controlled via Group Policy at `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > Enable NTFS long paths`.
>
> You can also enable the new long path behavior per app via the manifest [...]

Of course, this enables support for paths >260 characters long at the system (API) level. If an application has its own assumptions hardcoded about the max path length (for example `wchar_t mypath[_MAX_PATH];`) then no amount of system-level support can magically make that particular application work with longer paths.

Comment: not using windows 10, but +1 for detailed solution

Answer (score 0):

There's a program called `Cygwin` that let you use many of Linux bash terminal inside windows, I hope it will help you.

Comment: i've executed on cmd and cygwin already... are there any specific packages you think I should install for cygwin that could help ?

Comment: Have a look here and I hope it help: [How to delete a file with a path too long to be deleted](http://superuser.com/a/755301/613452)